# PHP output doesn't print in xml format

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i have the following code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT sponsor_path FROM sponsors WHERE conference_id = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($cid));

$sponsorsImg = $stmt->fetchall (PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>";
$xml_output .= "<sponsors>";
foreach ($sponsorsImg as $spImg){
    $xml_output .= "<sponsor>\n";
    $xml_output .= "<image>".$spImg->sponsor_path."</image>\n";
    $xml_output .= "</sponsor>\n";
}
$xml_output .= "</sponsors>";

echo $xml_output;
```

Instead of printing the results in xml format i get only the `$spImg->sponsor_path`'s content in plain text. Any ideas?

Comment: use right click on html page and `show source`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers will render markup that looks like XML. So it might be the case that the XML that you want is actually produced but not displayed correctly on the browser.

Try the following:

Set the content type before outputting:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $xml_output;
```

If the output looks the same, then right click on the page and select view source. You should see your XML markup as intended there.